# ElasticSearch how to map Nested Object as an Array?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose we have a collection of objects

```
{
  id: '10',
  items: {
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2',
    ...
  }
}
```

Would it be possible to map it as if it's an array of `"${k} ${v}"` items?

```
{
  id: '10',
  items: [
    'a 1',
    'b 2',
    ...
  ]
}
```

It's possible of course preprocess data before uploading it to ElasticSearch, but maybe there's a way to keep the
original structure of the data but map it as if it's an array?